# HTML code to reload website until a certain phrase is found

Tags: html, reload

I know almost nothing about HTML but I need HTML code which reloads certain website until a certain phrase is found.

Answer (score 2):

HTML has no features which would let you do this. You need a programming language. Pretty much any programming language will do the job.

For example, in [Perl](http://learn.perl.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.16;
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $not_found = 1;

while ($not_found) {
    sleep 60*5; # Every 5 minutes
    say "Trying…";
    $mech->get('http://example.com/test.html');
    my $text = $mech->text();
    $not_found = 0 if ($text =~ /some text/);
}

say "Found";
```

Comment: Which language do you recommend me?

Comment: @Nela are there any that you know already (e.g. c# , java, ruby, php, python)?

Comment: Well, no :D But I need something to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to search the html for a certain phrase and the let the javascript reload the page if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I´ll use Javascript or some javascript based framework like jQuery.
You can create a simple embedded script in your HTML file and declare inside a function like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){//jQuery function
        //wait 5 seconds before searching
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            var element = $('#phraseContainer');
            var content = element.text();
            if (content.indexOf('your desired phrase') != -1){
                alert('Phrase appears!!!');
            }
            else {
                location.reload();
            }
        },5000);
    });

</script>
```

Nota that you need some div element in your HTML code with the phraseContainer id like:

```
<div id="phraseContainer">some text in wich you want to search for</div>
```

Of course, this is not perfectly solution (if the text of the page does not change dinamically, you could fall into an infinite loop), but it can give you an idea of ​​the way forward